# How to programmatically clear/reset React-Select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

**ReactSelect V2** and **V3** seems to have several props like `clearValue`, `resetValue` and `setValue`. Whatever I'm trying, I'm not able to clear the selections programmatically. `resetValue` seems not to be accessible from the outside.

```
selectRef.setValue([], 'clear')
// or
selectRef.clearValue()
```

*This does not clear the current selection.*

Do I miss something here or is it not fully implemented yet?

Comment: You can use the value null

Comment: I tried and wasted my time using react-select. the simplicity of resetting the form is missing then why one should use this? it is made to much complicated and the tutorial is also something only the maker can understand.

Comment: yep. Rather than set it up with Ref which didn't work, the simplest solution which ended up working was just setting the value to null. <Select value={null} />

Answer (score 90):

I came across this problem myself and managed to fix it by passing a `key` to the React-Select component, with the selected value appended to it. This will then force the `ReactSelect` to re-render itself when the selection is updated.

I hope this helps someone.

```
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';

...

<ReactSelect
  key={`my_unique_select_key__${selected}`}
  value={selected || ''}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Really good one. In case your selected value is object, use ``my_unique_select_key__${JSON.stringify(selected)}``.

Comment: This works but note that it cases the input to lose focus. You can [refocus it imperatively](https://react-select.com/advanced#methods) if that matters.

Comment: Just `value={selected || ''}` solved it for me

Comment: can someone explain here what is `selected`? a variable or keyword or just string?

Comment: `selected` is stored in state somewhere whilst you are tracking the current state of the dropdown. This should be updated when the user makes a new selection. This will cause the key to change and will re-render the component, so passing it the currently selected value will ensure that it does so with the correct selection,

Comment: if value is an object `value={this.state.selected && Object.keys(this.state.selected).length ? this.state.selected : null}`

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's annoying that this works but it will force a re-render which is the heart of the issue.

Comment: This is so good. One-liner!!

Comment: Does anyone know what exactly `key` does that makes select component re-render?

Comment: @TheUnKnown The key is used to identify a component. When it changes, React thinks the component has changed and re-renders it. See documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: A bit hacky but a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: Works even if the value was previous fulfilled! Thanks!

Answer (score 64):

If you're using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) you can try to pass `null` to `value` prop.

For example:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const options = [
      { value: "one", label: "One" },
      { value: "two", label: "Two" }
    ];

    this.state = {
      select: {
        value: options[0], // "One" as initial value for react-select
        options // all available options
      }
    };
  }

  setValue = value => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      select: {
        ...prevState.select,
        value
      }
    }));
  };

  handleChange = value => {
    this.setValue(value);
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setValue(null); // here we reset value
  };

  render() {
    const { select } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Reset value
          </button>
        </p>
        <Select
          name="form-field-name"
          value={select.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={select.options}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/8256j5m3vl) a working example of this.

Comment: Please provide a (simplified) code-example in your answer, since links aren't permanent.

Comment: Hey, I am new to react-select, may i know what is this doing: `select: {
        value: options[0],
        options
      }

Comment: @AKJ The part `value: options[0]` means that react-select will have the option `"One"` as initial value. (also added explanatory comment for this line)

Comment: I will add that clearing the value only works with null. If you pass undefined (like I was), the selected value will remain..

Comment: nothing worked. react-select is hell.. too much complicated just to reset it. if we spend a day resetting a select control.. when should we submit it?

Comment: This doesn't work because the select box does not re-render when value is changed programatically.

Comment: working for me by passing the `null` value instead of an undefined or empty string

Answer (score 31):

You can clear the value of react select using the ref.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function App() {
  const selectInputRef = useRef();

  const onClear = () => {
    selectInputRef.current.clearValue();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Select Gender</h1>
      <Select
        ref={selectInputRef}
        options={[
          { value: "male", label: "Male" },
          { value: "female", label: "Female" }
        ]}
      />
      <button onClick={onClear}>Clear Value</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It shows me an error: The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<StateManager<any, false, Select<any, false>>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'

Comment: Hi @Zeeshan Ahmad can you please let me know how can i clear the values using the refs and not add them back to the options list ???

Comment: In case of `import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable'`, you need to use `creatableSelectRef.current.select.select.clearValue()`

Comment: just too reset a select box if we need to use ref then it's the end of a developer's life.

Comment: Thanks, you save my day. This way is the only way I find fit with my project, even just using `useRef` to only clear the select box.

Comment: @LaliteshUpadhyaya if you want to deal with typescript with this solution you should use the useRef<any>() generic version. That way you can get rid of the annoying ts error. Although I would preferably use selectInputRef.current.setValue("") to clear the select value in react-select version 5+.

Comment: selectInputRef.current.clearValue(); worked for me.

Comment: I have used the above example, getting following error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clearValue')

Comment: it woks, clean the value, but not show the placeholder ...
The example in sandbox has changed, is no more related to react-select....... ?!?
I found this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-clear-value-3d2xn

Answer (score 18):

Just store the value in the state, and change the state programmatically using componentDidUpdate etc...

```
class Example extends Component {

constructor() {
    super()
}

state = {
     value: {label: 'Default value', key : '001'}
}

render() {
   return(
      <Select
         ...
         value={this.state.value}
         ...
      />
   )
)}
```

Note: **'value' should be an object.**

Comment: Bravo for noting that Select value should be an object.

Comment: something out of the world but didn't worked too.

Answer (score 9):

A simple option would be to pass `null` to the `value` prop.

```
<Select value={null} />
```

Comment: If you choose this option, you should make a state for value, that gets set on every change, or your field will remain empty

Answer (score 6):

This is my working implementation of a [React-Select V3](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)  **cleared programmatically** with [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

You can play with it in the [CodeSandbox DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-select-v3-with-hooks-and-form-k0z5d). Any feedback is welcome.

```js
const initialFormState = { mySelectKey: null };

const [myForm, setMyForm] = useState(initialFormState);

const updateForm = value => {
  setMyForm({ ...myForm, mySelectKey: value });
};

const resetForm = () => {
  setMyForm(initialFormState);
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <form>

      <Select name = "mySelect"
           options = {options}
             value = {options.filter(({ value }) => value === myForm.mySelectKey)}
    getOptionLabel = {({ label }) => label}
    getOptionValue = {({ value }) => value}
          onChange = {({ value }) => updateForm(value)} />

      <p>MyForm: {JSON.stringify(myForm)}</p>

      <input type="button" value="Reset fields" onClick={resetForm} />

    </form>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I believe this approach converts a controlled component into an uncontrolled component?  are there any workarounds to avoid this error?

Answer (score 6):

Along the top answer, please note that the value needs to be "null" and not "undefined" to clear properly.

Answer (score 5):

If someone looking for solution using Hooks. React-Select V3.05:

```
const initial_state = { my_field: "" }

const my_field_options = [
    { value: 1, label: "Daily" },
    { value: 2, label: "Weekly" },
    { value: 3, label: "Monthly" },
]

export default function Example(){
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initial_state);

    function handleSelectChange(newValue, actionMeta){
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [actionMeta.name]: newValue ? newValue.value : ""
        })
    }

    return <Select
               name={"my_field"}
               inputId={"my_field"}
               onChange={handleSelectChange}
               options={my_field_options}
               placeholder={values.my_field}
               isClearable={true}
           /> 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

in v5, you can actually pass the prop `isClearable={true}` to make it clearable, which easily resets the selected value

Answer (score 3):

If you check Select component in React Developers panel you will see that it is wrapped by another – State Manager. So you ref is basically ref to State manager, but not to Select itself.

[image]

Luckily, StateManager has state) and a value object which you may set to whatever you want.

For example (this is from my project, resetGroup is onClick handler that I attach to some button in DOM):

```
<Select onChange={this.handleGroupSelect} 
      options={this.state.groupsName.map(group => 
                  ({ label: group, value: group }) )}
      instanceId="groupselect"
      className='group-select-container'
      classNamePrefix="select"
      placeholder={this.context.t("Enter name")}
      ref={c => (this.groupSelect = c)}
/>

    resetGroup = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            selectedGroupName: ""
        })
        this.groupSelect.state.value.value = ""
        this.groupSelect.state.value.label = this.context.t("Enter name")
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are working with function component, here's a **basic demo** of how you can reset the react select Based on some change/trigger/reduxValue.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const customReactSelect = ({ options }) => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([]);


  /**
   * Based on Some conditions you can reset your value
   */
  useEffect(() => {
      setSelectedValue([])
  }, [someReduxStateVariable]);

  const handleChange = (selectedVal) => {
    setSelectedValue(selectedVal);
  };

  return (
    <Select value={selectedValue} onChange={handleChange} options={options} />
  );
};

export default customReactSelect;
```

Answer (score 3):

To clear value of react-select programmatically:

```
let ref = useRef(null);
```

input field:

```
<Select ref={selectInputRef} ...other options/>
```

reset function / method:

```
const resetFilters = () => {selectInputRef.current.clearValue()};
```

most of users have shared the code with `selectInputRef.current.select.clearValue()`
but this one is for older version of `react-select`

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone, this is my solution: I created a button to clear the selected value by setting state back to it's initial value.

```
<button onClick={() => this.clearFilters()} >Clear</button>

clearFilters(){
    this.setState({ startTime: null })
}
```

Full code sample below:

```js
import React from "react"
import Select from 'react-select';

const timeSlots = [
    { value: '8:00', label: '8:00' },
    { value: '9:00', label: '9:00' },
    { value: '10:00', label: '10:00' },
] 

class Filter extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      startTime: null,
    }
  }
  
  startTime = (selectedTime) => {
    this.setState({ startTime: selectedTime });
  }

  clearFilters(){
    this.setState({
        startTime: null, 
    })
  }

  render(){
    const { startTime } = this.state;
    
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.clearFilters()} >Clear</button>
        <Select
            value={startTime}
            onChange={this.startTime}
            options={timeSlots}
            placeholder='Start time'
        />
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Filter
```

Comment: This doesn't make use of the react-select API for reseting values.

Comment: You can just do `<Select value={this.state.startTime} onChange={this.startTime}/>`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value to null

```
   const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState();
   const [valueList, setValueList] = useState([]); 
   const [loadingValueList, setLoadingValueList] = useState(true);


 useEffect(() => {
       //on page load update valueList and Loading as false
      setValueList(list);
      loadingValueList(false)
    }, []);

                                
  const onClear = () => {
     setSelectedValue(null);  // this will reset the selected value
  };

<Select
       className="basic-single"
       classNamePrefix="select"
       value={selectedValue}
       isLoading={loadingValueList}
       isClearable={true}
       isSearchable={true}
       name="selectValue"
       options={valueList}
       onChange={(selectedValue) => 
       setSelectedValue(selectedValue)}
      />
  <button onClick={onClear}>Clear Value</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

### react-select/creatable.

The question explicitly seeks a solution to react-select/creatable. Please find the below code, a simple answer and solution to the question. You may modify the code for your specific task.

```
import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";

const TestAction = (props) => {
  const { buttonLabelView, className } = props;
  const selectInputRef = useRef();

  function clearSelected() {
    selectInputRef.current.select.select.clearValue();
  }

  const createOption = (label, dataId) => ({
    label,
    value: dataId,
  });

  const Options = ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]?.map((post, id) => {
    return createOption(post, id);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <CreatableSelect
        ref={selectInputRef}
        name="dataN"
        id="dataN"
        className="selctInputs"
        placeholder=" Select..."
        isMulti
        options={Options}
      />

      <button onClick={(e) => clearSelected()}> Clear </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestAction;
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the top suggestions worked for me and they all seemed a bit over the top. Here's the important part of what worked for me

```
<Select 
    value={this.state.selected && Object.keys(this.state.selected).length ? this.state.selected : null},
    onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
/>
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Fixed my issue straight away.

Answer (score 1):

passing null in value attribute of the react-select will reset it.

Answer (score 1):

Nether of the solution help me.
This work for me:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

import Select from "react-select";
import { colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

export default class SingleSelect extends Component {
  selectRef = null;

  clearValue = () => {
    this.selectRef.select.clearValue();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Select
          ref={ref => {
            this.selectRef = ref;
          }}
          className="basic-single"
          classNamePrefix="select"
          defaultValue={colourOptions[0]}
          name="color"
          options={colourOptions}
        />
        <button onClick={this.clearValue}>clear</button>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are using formik then use below code to reset react-select value.

useEffect(()=>{
formik.setFieldValue("stateName", [])
},[])

Where stateName is html field name.

if you want to change value according to another dropdown/select (countryName) then pass that field value in useEffect array like below

useEffect(()=>{
formik.setFieldValue("stateName", [])
},[formik.values.countryName])
```

Answer (score 0):

Zeeshan's answer is indeed correct - you can use `clearValue()` but when you do so, the `Select` instance isn't reset to your `defaultValue` prop like you might be thinking it will be. `clearValue()` returns a general `Select...` label with no data in `value`.

You probably want to use **`selectOption()`** in your reset to explicitly tell  `react-select` **what value/label it should reset to**. How I wired it up (using `Next.js`, `styled-components` and `react-select`):

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Select from 'react-select'

// Basic button design for reset button
const UIButton = styled.button`
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 17px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
`

// Using style object `react-select` library indicates as best practice
const selectStyles = {
  control: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    borderRadius: 0,
    fontWeight: 700,
    margin: '0 20px 10px 0',
    padding: '10px',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    minWidth: '250px'
  })
}

export default function Sample() {
  // State for my data (assume `data` is valid)
  const [ currentData, setCurrentData ] = useState(data.initial)

  // Set refs for each select you have (one in this example)
  const regionOption = useRef(null)

  // Set region options, note how I have `data.initial` set here
  // This is so that when my select resets, the data will reset as well
  const regionSelectOptions = [
    { value: data.initial, label: 'Select a Region' },
    { value: data.regionOne, label: 'Region One' },    
  ]

  // Changes data by receiving event from select form
  // We read the event's value and modify currentData accordingly
  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    setCurrentData(e.value)
  }

  // Reset, notice how you have to pass the selected Option you want to reset
  // selectOption is smart enough to read the `value` key in regionSelectOptions 
  // All you have to do is pass in the array position that contains a value/label obj
  // In my case this would return us to `Select a Region...` label with `data.initial` value
  const resetData = () => {
    regionOption.current.select.selectOption(regionSelectOptions[0])
    setCurrentData(data.initial)
  }

  // notice how my `UIButton` for the reset is separate from my select menu
  return(
    <>
    <h2>Select a region</h2>
    <Select 
      aria-label="Region select menu"
      defaultValue={ regionSelectOptions[0] }
      onChange={ event => handleDataChange(event) }
      options={ regionSelectOptions }
      ref={ regionOption }
      styles={ selectStyles }
    />
    <UIButton 
      onClick={ resetData }
    >
      Reset
    </UIButton>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StateManager is abolished now, at least after version 5.5.0.
Now if you use ref, you can just do it like this:

```
selectRef = null
<Select
  ...
  ref={c => (selectRef=c)}
/>
clearValue = () => {
   selectRef.clearValue();
};
```

Here this `c` would be the `Select2` React Component

Answer (score 0):

This bugged me so here it is:

React select uses arrays so you have to pass an **empty array** not null.

Using React's useState:

```
import ReactSelect from 'react-select'

const Example = () => {

     const [val, setVal] = useState()

     const reset = () => {
         setVal([])
     }

     return <ReactSelect  
         value={val}/>
}

export default Example
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function called onClear, and setSelected to empty string.
2. Inside the handle submit function, call the onClear function.

This will work perfectly.

Example code:

```
const onClear = () => {
  setSelected("");
};
    
const handleSubmit = ()=>{
 1 your data first ......(what you are posting or updating)
 2 onClear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was desperately looking for the correct answer with TypeScript. I finally found the answer by looking at the internal code.

Package version from my package.json:
`"react-select": "^5.7.7",`

First, you need to import `SelectInstance` alongside `Select`:

```
import Select, { SelectInstance } from 'react-select'
```

Then, create a ref from it:

```
const selectRef = useRef<SelectInstance<DefaultOption> | null>(null)
```

`DefaultOption` is something like this btw:

```
export type DefaultOption = {
  readonly value: string
  readonly label: string
}
```

Finally

```
<Select
  ref={selectRef}
  // other props...
/>

<button onClick={() => { selectRef.current?.clearValue() }}>Clear Value</button>
```

Note: this is for single select, didn't try it for a multi select. But it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a state where you can set null - this will clear the input.

```
const GENDER_VALUES = [
  { label: 'Male', value: 'm' },
  { label: 'Female', value: 'f' }
];

const MyComponent = () => {

//...

const [gender, setGender] = useState(null)

//...

return (
<>
   <MySelect
      options={GENDER_VALUES}
      onChange={(gender) => setGender(gender.value)}
      value={GENDER_VALUES.filter((gender) => gender.value === gender)) || null}
   />
   <button onClick={() => setGender(null)}>Reset</button>
</>
)}
```

Note the `value` prop on the `<MySelect/>` component- it will set the select to empty if there isn't a gender stored in state.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the value from any `react-select` component use .clearValue()

For example:

```
import Creatable from 'react-select/creatable'

const genericNameRef = useRef(null);
```

react-select component:

```
<Creatable isClearable={true} id='Generic-name-select' options={modifiedSaltOptions} onChange={handleChangeNewSalt} onCreateOption={handleGenericCreateOption} ref={genericNameRef} placeholder='Generic name' />
```

function to clear value:
This function is added on add button, when all the values are set at the end you can use this

```
const addMedicine = () => {
 genericNameRef.current.clearValue()
 };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if you are using formik then use below code to reset react-select value.

useEffect(()=>{
formik.setFieldValue("stateName", [])
},[])

Where stateName is html field name.

if you want to change value according to another dropdown/select (countryName) then pass that field value in useEffect array like below

useEffect(()=>{
formik.setFieldValue("stateName", [])
},[formik.values.countryName])
```

Answer (score -3):

I use redux-observable.

Initial state:

```
firstSelectData: [],
secondSelectData:[],
secondSelectValue: null
```

I create an action for filling first select. on change of first select, I call an action to fill second one.

In success of fill first select I set (`secondSelectData` to `[]`, `secondSelectValue` to `null`)

In success of fill second select I set (`secondSelectValue` to `null`)
on change of second select, I call an action to update `secondSelectValue` with the new value selected