# How to reset the react-select component to defaultValue state after form submit

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In the below code I have a simple react component which has a form containing a react-select component. It initially displays the defaultValue and then gives two options to select. Once selected the submit button would send a post request. 
Every thing works fine point the issue is that I want to revert the Select component to display the default value after on submit is clicked.

```
import Select from 'react-select';

export class Test extends Component {
  this.setState = {
    selection: 0,
   };

  onSelectChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selection: e.value });
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { selection } = this.state;
    // Post request logic comes here
    // Reset Select component to original default state
  }

  render() {
    const defaultValue = { label: 'Choose something', value: 0 };
    const options = [
      { label: 'Item 1', value: 1 },
      { label: 'Item 2', value: 2 },
    ];

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <Select
          options={options}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          onChange={this.onSelectChange}
        />
       //submit button here          
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to add a value parameter and set `value={null}`

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically clear/reset react-select v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412843/how-to-programmatically-clear-reset-react-select-v2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Select from 'react-select';

export class Test extends Component {
  this.setState = {
    selection: 0,
   };

  onSelectChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selection: e.value });
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { selection } = this.state;
    // Post request logic comes here
    // Reset Select component to original default state
    this.setState({selection: 0});
  }

  render() {

    const options = [
      { label: 'Choose something', value: 0 },
      { label: 'Item 1', value: 1 },
      { label: 'Item 2', value: 2 },
    ];

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <Select
          options={options}
          value={this.state.selection}
          onChange={this.onSelectChange}
        />
       //submit button here          
      </form>
    );
```

Use value prop instead of defaultValue and manage it through state.On Submit, reset that state to initial value i.e 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using component state, all you have to do is add `value = {this.state.selection}` as a prop on your `<Select>` component. After your post statement(either using promise or async), do `this.setState({selection: 0})` and it'll reset your `<Select>` back to value 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use component lifecycle methods also

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
```

After submitting the form, props will change

```
if (this.state.selection === nextProps.value && this.state.selection !== 0) {
  this.setState({ selection: 0 });
}
```