# Clear react-select v2 input field from parent component reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

So, I have parent class, where I press button, and then call 'clearValue' method of `TagSelector`, where I need to clear `AsyncCreatableSelect` input.

`TagSelector` class:

```
export default class TagSelector extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tagDownloaded: []
        };


      clearValue = () => {
        console.log(this.refs.acs);
        console.log("here I need to clear AsyncCreatableSelect"); // comment
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <AsyncCreatableSelect
                ref="acs"
                cacheOptions
                loadOptions={this.promiseOptions}
                isMulti
                defaultOptions={this.state.tagDownloaded}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

I read api and know that 'clearValue' prop-method can help, but how - I don't know.

Comment: You have to make it work using state and props. 

state = {
agDownloaded: [],
selectedValues: []
}

<AsyncCreatableSelect value={this.state.selectedValues} ...

To clear the selection do a this.setState({selectedValues: []})

handleChange(values) {this.setState({selectedValues: values})}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Select feature has option to set select box value - to any of the field / reset as well. Just found below link with working demo , doing reset of select programatically.
Refer it - 
[How to programmatically clear/reset react-select v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412843/how-to-programmatically-clear-reset-react-select-v2)
https://codesandbox.io/s/8256j5m3vl