# reset value of React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I need to reset the react select value, when I click on a button I need to reset to the default value of react select, the data is provided from api, how can I do this ??

maybe I need to guard the value because I cannot lost the value selected if the user refresh the page

code below:

```
class SelectTabs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      options: [],
    };

    this.getDataTab = this.getDataTab.bind(this);
    this.makeOptions = this.makeOptions.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataTab();
  }

  getDataTab() {
    const URL = `${Utils.ngrok_service}/tab/tabGet`;
    const skills = this.props.manager.workerClient.attributes.routing.skills;

    axios.post(URL).then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          options: [...response.data.SAC, ...response.data.AC],
    });
  }

  makeOptions(object) {
    const options = object.map((data, index) => {
      return {
        value: index + 1 + '. ' + data,
        label: index + 1 + '. ' + data,
      };
    });

    return options;
  }

  render() {
    const selectProps = {
      isRtl: false,
      isMulti: false,
      isClearable: false,
      isSearchable: false,
      placeholder: 'Selecione',
      noOptionsMessage: () => 'Não Encontrado.',
    };

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <SC.Container>
          <SC.Title>Tabulação</SC.Title>
          <Select
            {...selectProps}
            options={this.makeOptions(this.state.options)}
          />
```

Comment: you could set the state back to an empty array if you want to reset the value.

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412843/how-to-programmatically-clear-reset-react-select