# How to clear a value from react-select in TypeScript using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-select, react-typescript

I've tried looking at several answers in SO but all of them either are in normal javascript and don't take in account Typescript at all, with Javascript works fine without types but TSX is a little different and I'm just beginning in React. I'm using `react-select` component for the select.

Option/IOption class/interface

```
export interface IOption {
  value: string | null;
  label: string;
  icon?: string;
}

export class Option implements IOption {
  public value:string | null;
  public label: string;
  public icon?: string | undefined;
  constructor(){
    this.value = null;
    this.label = "";
  }
}
```

AlergiaForm.Component.tsx

```
const AlergiaForm = () => { 
    //For sake of simplicity, ignoring rest of the code
    const option = new Option();
    option.value = "5"; //hardcoding to test react-select clear value or selection
    const[comprador, setComprador] = useState(option);

    //When dropdown changes, it detects the value and save it to another state
    //This is working fine to grab the value...
    const handleDropDownChange = (selectedOption: SingleValue<IOption>, name: string):void 
      => {
        const { value } = {...selectedOption};
        setFormFields({...formFields, [name] : value});
    }
    
    //Changing the "comprador" option to new Option() so it "clears" the value, but not working...
    const resetFields = () => {
        setComprador(new Option());
    }

    //Populating options as IOption that react-select is using 
    const options = [
        { value: '1', label: 'First value' },
        { value: '5', label: 'This should be selected, but no' },
        { value: '6', label: 'Other stuff' }
      ] as IOption[];

    return(
        <>
            {/*The value={comprador} is not complaining, but the dropdown does not populate any value or allows to make it selected (it grabs the value in the handleDropDownChange(), but is not displaying it correctly) */}
            <Select onChange={(selectedOption) => handleDropDownChange(selectedOption, "fieldName")} options={options} value={comprador} />
            <button onClick={resetFields}>Reset</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default AlergiaForm;
```

Example in JS that they say it works, but didn't for me:
[How to programmatically clear/reset React-Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412843/how-to-programmatically-clear-reset-react-select)

Result of what's happening (react-select should have a text saying "Select..." and when I choose an option it's still blank:
[image: Dropdown bad]

"Working" example of the behavior
[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-dewdney-pgwkym?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: There should not be any diff with ts its just type that will get striped anyway.

Comment: Can you add the js SO answer?

Comment: Updating the post with the JS answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412843/how-to-programmatically-clear-reset-react-select

Comment: Can you make https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated answer with Repl code. You can see the behavior. Maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: Can you make the example in other platform where i can view and edit the code like codesandbox

Comment: I don't know why did you use `Option` class but https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/competent-surf-tg7jck Is this right?

Comment: I added the codesandbox code

Comment: @kennarddh that worked, I just needed the `useState<SingleValue<IOption> | null>(null)`. You can post the code as answer and I'll mark it as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the default state to null like in the docs.

Also you need to add the type to the state to fix typescript cannot assign to null

```
useState<SingleValue<IOption> | null>(null)
```

Comment: Thanks, just for future references, this helped too `useState<SingleValue<IOption> | null>(null)` aside from make it null.

Comment: It only help to fix types error but ok